# Print out the index of a map function

Tags: python, functional-programming

I am trying to play around with some more of function programming parts of python and for a test I thought I would print out the sum of the first n integers for all numbers between 1 and 100.

```
for i in map(lambda n: (n*(n+1))/2, range(1,101)):
     print "sum of the first %d integers: %d" % (i,i)
```

The last line prints out as:

```
sum of the first 5050 integers: 5050
```

It should read "sum of the first 100 integers is 5050 (I may have an off by one error but I'll fix that).

My question is what is variable that holds the index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return tuple with (index, value) from your lambda, like that:

```
for i,s in map(lambda n: (n,(n*(n+1))/2), range(1,101)):
    print "sum of the first %d integers: %d" % (i,s)
```

Comment: you beat me to the exact same answer by about 30 sec.

Comment: Or even less. Nice! But you've beaten me with comment.

Answer (score 4):

Your code doesn't define a variable that holds an index.  In the outermost scope, there is just the variable (sometimes called a "name" when talking about Python) "i".

If you'd like an index, you can use the built-in function enumerate()

```
for i,x in enumerate([5,10,15]):
    print i, x
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could try this:

```
for ind, val in enumerate(map(lambda n: (n*(n+1))/2, range(1,101)), 1):
    print "sum of the first %d integers: %d" % (ind, val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mayby I don't understand what you are going for but couldn't you just use print

```
print "sum of the first %d integers: %d" %(100,sum(xrange(1,101)))
```

if you wanted user input...

```
i = input("Enter the upper range to sum: ")
print "sum of the first %d integers: %d" %(i,sum(xrange(1,i+1)))
```

I'm also using xrange() because it is faster in python v2 than range().

Comment: google "functional programming" to learn a little more about what he's trying to do. It's not necessarily the best way *for this particular task*, but for others it can be.

Comment: I was trying to print out the "sum of the first X integers is Y" for the first 100 numbers just as an exercise with no goal.  Also be aware that there are easier ways to sum a sequence of numbers that are faster than using brute force.